# Wep api .NET C#: how can I select only a few attribute from a model using a GET method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to have a GET method that selects only some attributes from this model:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionId { get; set; }
        public int UserProfessionFieldId { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }
        public byte[]? UserPicture { get; set; }
        public virtual Profession UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<DataUsage> DataUsages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Among these attributes, I would like to get the `IdUser`, the `UserName`, the `UserMail`, the `UserCompany`, the `Profession` (another model from which I would like to have only the `id`, `IdProfession`, and the `name`, `ProfessionName`) and the `ProfessionField` (same than for `Profession`).

I'm not interested in getting the `UserProfessionId`, `UserProfessionFieldId`,the `UserPicture` or the DataUsage.

From Profession, I would like to get only the id and the name. Here's the model:

```
namespace Sims.Models
{
    public partial class Profession
    {
        public Profession()
        {
            ProfessionFields = new HashSet<ProfessionField>();
            Users = new HashSet<User>();
        }

        public int IdProfession { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<ProfessionField> ProfessionFields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now this is the get method that I want to improve:

```
 // GET: api/Users
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUsers()
 {
    return await _context.Users
        //.Include(u => u.UserProfession)
          .Select(u => new User {
                 IdUser = u.IdUser,
                 UserName =u.UserName,
                 UserMail = u.UserMail,
                 UserCompany = u.UserCompany,
                 UserProfessionField = u.UserProfessionField
             }).ToListAsync();
        }
```

And this is the current result:

```
[
  {
    "idUser": 1,
    "userProfessionId": 0,
    "userProfessionFieldId": 0,
    "userName": "user_test",
    "userMail": "mail@test.com",
    "userCompany": "TestCompany",
    "userPicture": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": {
      "idProfessionField": 1,
      "professionFieldName": "Sports",
      "professionId": 1,
      "profession": null,
      "users": []
    },
    "dataUsages": [
      {
        "idDataUsage": 1,
        "openDataId": 1,
        "dateOfUsage": "2020-01-19T19:55:33",
        "dataFormatId": 18,
        "languageId": 1,
        "isDownloaded": 0,
        "usedBy": 1,
        "dataFormat": null,
        "language": null,
        "openData": null,
        "usedByNavigation": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idUser": 2,
    "userProfessionId": 0,
    "userProfessionFieldId": 0,
    "userName": "roger_federer",
    "userMail": null,
    "userCompany": null,
    "userPicture": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": {
      "idProfessionField": 1,
      "professionFieldName": "Sports",
      "professionId": 1,
      "profession": null,
      "users": []
    },
    "dataUsages": [
      {
        "idDataUsage": 2,
        "openDataId": 1,
        "dateOfUsage": "2020-09-02T13:43:10",
        "dataFormatId": 18,
        "languageId": 2,
        "isDownloaded": 0,
        "usedBy": 2,
        "dataFormat": null,
        "language": null,
        "openData": null,
        "usedByNavigation": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "idUser": 3,
    "userProfessionId": 0,
    "userProfessionFieldId": 0,
    "userName": null,
    "userMail": null,
    "userCompany": null,
    "userPicture": null,
    "userProfession": null,
    "userProfessionField": {
      "idProfessionField": 4,
      "professionFieldName": "API dev",
      "professionId": 3,
      "profession": null,
      "users": []
    },
    "dataUsages": [
      {
        "idDataUsage": 3,
        "openDataId": 2,
        "dateOfUsage": "2022-08-10T07:08:02",
        "dataFormatId": 10,
        "languageId": 1,
        "isDownloaded": 1,
        "usedBy": 3,
        "dataFormat": null,
        "language": null,
        "openData": null,
        "usedByNavigation": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: Don't use your Entity Framework models in your web app. Use a model specifically designed to sit inside your domain logic that isn't polluted with all the stuff you don't want to send back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Create small DTO (Data Transfer Object) objects that include only the attributes you want to get.

```
 public partial class UserDto
{
    public long IdUser { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? UserMail { get; set; }
    public string? UserCompany { get; set; }

    public virtual ProfessionDto UserProfession { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ProfessionFieldDto UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class ProfessionDto
{
    public int IdProfession { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class ProfessionFieldDto // idk why its same but here you are
{
    public int IdProfession { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Then you can fill them and return them. You can use AutoMapper for filling them, or fill them by yourself. :-).

Using automapper:

```
    // GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDto>>> GetUsers()
    {
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDto>>(_context.Users.ToListAsync());
}
```

By yourself:

```
// GET: api/Users
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UserDto>>> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = _context.Users.ToList();
        var userDtos = new List<UserDto>();
        foreach(var user in users){
               userDtos.Add(new UserDto{Id = user.id..., Name = user.name...}
        }
        return userDtos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that !

I just had this idea but when I tried to add the controller for the dto I had an issue with the context file :/

As my api is currently linked to a MySQL database I don't know if the issue comes from there ! 

But I'll try again !

Thanks :)

Comment: The issue you're describing shouldn't make your choice of backing database relevant, so it won't be that for sure

Comment: So I tried this solution and it's almost fully working !

The only issue I get is when I add a new UserDTO object, I cannot add any UserProfession as it cannot convert Profession type to ProfessionDTO

Comment: You need to add each model to the automapper map, so the same way that you would do PersonDTO->Person, you need to do a mapping configuration for UserProfessionDTO->UserProfession, it can all be done within the same mapping profile though, and the reverse mapping if you're also converting them the other way, as would usually be done if you also insert users via that api etc. hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning your entity model as the result set, either create a model for the returned object containing the properties you want within it and map it using something like [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), eg.

```
{
    public partial class PublicUser
    {
        public User()
        {
            DataUsages = new HashSet<DataUsage>();
        }

        public long IdUser { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? UserMail { get; set; }
        public string? UserCompany { get; set; }

        public virtual ProfessionField UserProfessionField { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Followed by:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PublicUser>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return yourMapper.Map<IEnumerable<PublicUser>>(await _context.Users
                .Include(u => u.UserProfession)
                .Select(u => new User {
                    IdUser = u.IdUser,
                    UserName =u.UserName,
                    UserMail = u.UserMail,
                    UserCompany = u.UserCompany,
                    UserProfessionField = u.UserProfessionField
                })
                .ToListAsync());
        }
;
```

Or alternatively if you're locked into using that model, you can consider ignoring null values within your json configuration, and then avoid sending the null values that way, eg.

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x =>
            {
                x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                x.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

Hope that helps :)